# HAProxy in kubernetes to connect galera cluster

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, haproxy, galera

I want to connect Galera cluster from `haproxy` pod deployed in kubernetes.

Docker file for the image.

```
FROM haproxy:2.3
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

`haproxy.cfg` File

```
defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    retries 10
    timeout client 10000
    timeout connect 100500
    timeout server 10000
frontend mysql-router-service
    bind *:6446
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend galera_cluster_backend
# MySQL Cluster BE configuration
backend galera_cluster_backend
    mode tcp
    #option mysql-check user haproxy
    option tcp-check 
    balance source
    server mysql_cluster_01 192.168.1.2:3306  check weight 1
    server mysql_cluster_02 192.168.1.3:3306  check weight 1
    server mysql_cluster_03 192.168.1.4:3306  check weight 1
```

Here `mysql-router-service` may mislead, but we used it as it was the earlier db connectivity service.

Kubernetes deployment manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ha-proxy
  namespace: mysql-router
spec:
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ha-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ha-proxy
        version: v1
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: dreg
      containers:
      - name: ha-proxy
        image: our-registry:5000/haproxy:v14
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6446
```

Kubernetes service manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-router-service
  namespace: mysql-router
  labels:
    app: ha-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    app: ha-proxy
    version: v1
  ports:
  - name: ha-proxy
    port: 6446
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6446
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.1.101
```

Followings were seen in `ha-proxy` pod logs

```
[WARNING] 237/114804 (1) : config : log format ignored for frontend 'mysql-router-service' since it has no log address.
[NOTICE] 237/114804 (1) : New worker #1 (8) forked
```

If we use `option  mysql-check user haproxy` in config file, Galera logs `/var/log/mysql/error.log` has

```
[Warning] Access denied for user 'haproxy'@'192.168.1.10' (using password NO)
```

Here `192.168.1.10` is one of k8 worker.

In galera cluster we have following users

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Host          | User        |
+---------------+-------------+    
| 192.168.1.%   | haproxy     |  
| localhost     | mariadb.sys |
| localhost     | mysql       |
| localhost     | root        |
+---------------+-------------+
```

All nodes are running `Ubuntu 18-04`, `ufw` is disabled.

We can telnet to galera nodes from k8 workers. (telnet `192.168.1.2 3306`)

What we had missed here?

Comment: does user `haproxy` have password ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes, tried with `haproxy` user with password. But still no connection

Answer (score 1):

Depends on :

`[Warning] Access denied for user 'haproxy'@'192.168.1.10' (using password NO)`

I think you have to set password for user : `haproxy`.

Comment: Yes, I had tried with a password and same access, But still it couldnt connect. Or do I have give password in `haproxy.cfg`?

Comment: follow up this : https://computingforgeeks.com/galera-cluster-high-availability-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-centos/

Comment: `bind *:6446` this should be myql port that is 3306 if I corrrect ?

Comment: As I said, we have to bind it to kubernetes service running on `6446`, we gave`bind 192.168.1.20:6446`, but still couldnt connect

Comment: how is `mysql -u haproxy -p xxx -h 192.168.1.2:6446` , 192.168.1.2

Comment: `telnet 192.168.1.2 6446`, I get > 5.5.5-10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~bionic
, but for for `mysql login` gets `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.1.2:6446' (-2)`